# assign values from javascript and get values from c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html

On the `btn1` click:

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="HTxtPath" />
                         or
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HTxtPath" />

<input id="btn1" type="button" value="save" onclick="Save()">

function Save() {
    document.getElementById('HTxtPath').value = "~/path/Order.pdf";
}
```

Upto here the values assigning to the hidden text, then

On the `btn2` click:

```
<input id="btn2" runat="server" type="button" value="save" onclick="Get()">

C#:

String data = HTxtPath.Value;
```

Here i m not getting the value

Pls help me

Comment: are you using asp.net forms or mvc?

Comment: am using using asp.net

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can do is to make the hidden input and asp.net hidden control instead of normal html input

Comment: you need to make the asp hidden control ClientIdMode to static to let js get its id

Answer (score 0):

used asp hidden field to store value

asp:HiddenField ID="hdnResultValue" Value="0" runat="server"

document.getElementById("hdnResultValue").value = 123;

following line read hidden field value

string codeBehindValue = hdnResultValue.Value;

Comment: $('#<%=TestHidden.ClientID %>').val("~/path/Order.pdf");

Comment: used this code when you assing value to hidden field

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

            $(function () {
                $('#<%=TestHidden.ClientID %>').val("~/path/Order.pdf");
                alert("Called");
            });});

Comment: $(document).ready(function () { 
 $(function () { 
   $('#<%="PUT HERE YOUR HIDDEN CONTROL ID".ClientID %>').val("~/path/Order.pdf"); 
 });
});